# redirect to requested page after login

Tags: java, jsp, session, redirect, web.xml

I have a java web application on JBoss.
The issue is that you are not redirected to the requested page after relogin following a session timeout.
Example:

1. You are at http://localhost:8082/myapp/#/admin/unr?tab=config
2. Session expired -> thrown to  http://localhost:8082/myapp/login.jsp
3. Put username/password and Enter
4. Redirected to  http://localhost:8082/myapp/index.html

Notes:

- My client is **Angular** based, and I'm using Angular's hash key #
- My **web.xml**:

  ```
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
   version="2.4">

   <display-name>My Application</display-name>


    <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>CSS</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/styles/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/fonts/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/assets/images/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>

     <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
       <description>These pages are only accessible by authorized administrators.</description>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
        <description>These are the roles who have access</description>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.jsp?error=error</form-error-page>
     </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <error-page>
     <error-code>403</error-code>
     <location>/login.jsp?unauthorized=unauthorized</location>
    </error-page>


    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

  </web-app>
  ```
- My **login.jsp** has a simple form with j_security_check action:

  ```
   <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="/j_security_check">
      <fieldset>
        <!-- Username input-->
        <div class="form-group">
           <input id="usernameInput" name="j_username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" required="">
        </div>

        <!-- Password input-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="password" name="j_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required="">
         </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary sign-in-btn" type="submit">
          Sign in
        </button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  ```

I think this is a server issue: there should be a way to instruct the application to return to the previous page, and not to index.html. Right?

Answer (score 0):

First you should create a class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class
here is the example

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class).formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                    //In this you can Redirect your desired view 
                }
            }).failureUrl("/loginError");

}       
}
```

Comment: I don't use Spring. my war is J2EE based

Comment: But in your code and explanation you didn't mention

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

j_security_check worked fine. The problem is that the server doesn't save the part after the hashbang (#) for redirecting (# is being used in Angularjs for routing).
When session timeouts, the server sends me to the login page, BUT the url in the address bar still points to the requested page. So I saved the url in localStorage, and in my main controller that is invoked on successful login, I checked for that variable:

in **login.jsp**:

```
     if(window.localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem("redirectToUrl", window.location.hash);
     }
```

in Angular **main.controller.js**:

```
angular.module('myappp')
 .controller('MainViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {

  if (window.localStorage && localStorage.redirectToUrl) {
     window.location = window.location.pathname + localStorage.redirectToUrl;
     localStorage.removeItem("redirectToUrl");
  } else {
     $state.go('app.instances.list');
 }
}]);
```